# angularJS add JSON by http request

Tags: json, angularjs

want to download a JSON of beercat('bieres.json') in this.bieres
How could I do?

```
 function() {
      var app = angular.module('monStore', []);

    app.service('dataService', function($http) { 

    this.getData = function() {
         return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'bieres.json'
         });
     }
    });

        app.controller('StoreController', function($scope,dataService){

         this.bieres = [];

        dataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.bieres = dataResponse.data;
        });

    ...

      });
```

I think it's my access by this.bieres that it's wrong,

the Json is loaded in the console, but a blank page is in result

Comment: Show the code you tried then. Tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.  And don't try to use a variable that you haven't declared yet.

Comment: xcuz me, i've put all my afternoon code to the trash

Comment: Then re-read the documentation of $http, try again, and come back here with the new code.

Comment: i think my problem is that is asynchron.